# What is the meaning of this sentence from Pynchon's Gravity's Rainbow:

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

From Gravity's Rainbow:

> "Osbie Feel stands in the minstrels' gallery, holding one of the biggest of Pirate's bananas so that it protrudes out the fly of his striped pajama bottoms-stroking with his other hand the great jaundiced curve in triplets against 4/4 toward the ceiling, he acknowledges dawn with the following: ..."

What is the meaning of "curve in triplets" and "against 4/4"?
How is 4/4 pronounced here - 4 by 4?

Comment: The noun phrase  is **the jaundiced curve** (the banana) and it is the direct object of the verb **stroking** in the verb phrase **stroking with his hand ... in triplets against 4/4 toward the ceiling**.  4/4 is pronounced  "four four" and the reference is to a musical time signature.

Comment: Thank you. What does "in triplets" mean here?

Comment: Congratulations. You are reading one of the most hard-to-read authors of the second part of the 20th century. His hands are doing two different things, here. One is holding the banana and the other is, well, can't you figure it out? Waltz time in music is given as 3/4. So, he's doing his activity in waltz time. It's a pretty over-the-top image. Good old Pynchon. So little is known about the man....

Comment: Have you looked the word **triplet** up in any dictionary?  You know now that 4/4 is a musical reference. We willingly give help with syntax and grammar and unusual words here, but basic questions that could be answered by consulting a dictionary are off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the word **"curve"** does not go with "in triplets" - it goes with the phrase "the great jaundiced curve."  [Jaundice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaundice) is a disease that results in yellowish skin, so "the great jaundiced curve" is just a fancy way of saying "the large, yellow, curved object," referring to the banana.

Next, this phrase: "stroke...in triplets against 4/4" is actually more about music theory than about standard English.  This sentence is a very vivid metaphor for experienced musicians, but not really for anyone else.

4/4 (pronounced "four-four") or ["common time"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_signature#common_time) is a musical time signature with four beats per measure, with the first beat of the four being the strongest, followed by three weaker beats.  It is by far the most frequently-used time signature in Western music, with almost all current popular music being written in 4/4.

Triplets, on the other hand, are three equally-spaced musical notes. To say that you're playing triplets **against** 4/4 means that in the time that the music plays four beats, you only play three, meaning that your beats are one-third again as slow as the underlying music.  This is called a [polyrhythm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyrhythm) and is a fairly advanced and somewhat difficult musical technique. If you go to YouTube and search for "polyrhythm 3 against 4", you'll find lots of videos of people trying to teach this advanced technique.

So, getting back to Pynchon: **"...stroking with his other hand...in triplets against 4/4...."** What this evokes (at least to an experienced musician) is a rhythmic stroking which, despite being even and regular, still demands a large amount of concentration and, above all, deliberate and tense restraint. When playing three against four, you have to *hold back* each note because the surrounding music is going faster than you. As a metaphor for masturbation, it's quite vivid.